# MODBUS RS-485 RTU

Tags: plc

[image]
can I use this type cable for MODBUS RTU which master 140M far from slaves ?

Comment: 140 miles is a lot of cable. It's 'm' if you mean meters. Capitals matter!

Comment: As long as impedances are matched ... ok with HDX there’s no crosstalk .. measure or lookup Z

Comment: What are the cable specs? Does the cable have a manufacturer and product code printed on it to find the specs?

Comment: could you provide the wire section? it seems thick.

Answer (score 1):

According to the "MODBUS over Serial Line Specification and Implementation Guide V1.02" document published on the official [website](https://www.modbus.org/specs.php) of Modbus, RS485 can be used in 2-wire and 4-wire configuration as duplex or half duplex communication. I will assume that you are using 2-wire configuration given the number of wires at the picture, the RS-485 standard defines specific max. lengths according to baud rates, cable(gauge, capacitance or characteristic impedance), number of loads in case of a daisy chain connection. According to the document, for a maximum of 9600 baud rate and 26AWG or lower(>0.14mm2) the maximum length is 1000m. I cannot see from the picture if the cable has a twisted pair. RS485 standard requires a twisted pair for balanced communication and a third wire for common. Avoiding a twisted pair could potentially present a red flag at those lengths.

It is also important how you connect the slaves. They should be connected in daisy chain configuration, or if a multi port tap is used then apply no longer than 20m cable derivations(branches). It is always important to use termination resistor at the furthest point and connect the shield properly at one end to the protective ground.

To sum up my answer, If your cable has a twisted pair and your network is properly connected and terminated, I can't see any problems that would be introduced by using this cable. However, I believe that it is crucial that the cable has a twisted pair because if it doesn't then: best case scenario it would only lower the communication speeds due to time lost in CRC error detection, worst case scenario is that the errors would be so great that even CRC code would not help it.

I think that the lengths should not be a problem if you use lower baud rates and implement a shielded twisted pair with a gauge above 0.14mm2(<26AWG).

Comment: thank you, but i dont understand what do you mean when you say (if a multi port tap is used then apply no longer than 20m cable)?

Comment: @molidasynchronize If you see figure 19 in the document, you will have passive and active taps that on one side connect the slave and on the other connect the continuation of the network. The slave branch which is connected to that tap should not be longer than 20m. This does not apply to your case if you don't use taps. If you found this answer helpful please feel free to rate it as best answer.